# htaccess Old files with .php new files without php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Hello everyone my problem is ..
I'm working on codeigniter i'm redirecting all my urls in one controller home

Using this code in  application/config/routes.php

```
$route['(.*)'] = "Home/index";
```

And any other files that i want run with different controllers

I do something like this

```
$route['test/get']="test/get";
$route['test/index']="test/index";
```

And at the end of the route file i add this line

```
$route['(.*)'] = "Home/index";
```

Inside of home controller i handle all urls ....

Everything is working fine

My .htaccess file look like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Now my problem is

I have old site http://www.example.com/

All pages are simple php pages like

```
http://www.example.com/one.php  
http://www.example.com/two.php  
http://www.example.com/three.php
```

This code is running without any php framework

Now new site with same domain http://www.example.com/
Running on php framework codeigniter without .php extension

```
  http://www.example.com/one
  http://www.example.com/two  
  http://www.example.com/three
```

Now all this pages or url is handle by one controller

Now what i want When ever any user search in google or any other search engine and they found link something like

```
http://www.example.com/one.php
```

When they click on this link ...
We should redirect them to

```
http://www.example.com/one
```

How can we do that

**Edit**
I have sub route that all sub routes also working from one controller

```
  http://www.example.com/one/x/y
  http://www.example.com/two/p  
  http://www.example.com/three/q/r/s
```

I want to remove .php from the end of the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the string before `.php` and then send a 301 redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?([\w\/_\.-]*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

This way you tell the search engines to update links they have in their systems to use the new ones without losing any SEO reputation you build.

**Edit:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
```

You need to add this `RewriteCond` to the file to grab all new CodeIgniter routes. This would result in the following overall `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule ^/?([\w\/_\.-]*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: its working fine but if i have sub folder in that domain

Comment: only it's working for one sub level i don't know too much about .htaccess please help

Comment: You need to replace the first `RewriteRule` with ```RewriteRule ^/?([\w\/_\.-]*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]```

Comment: When entered on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ with url as input `http://www.example.com/three/q/r/s.php` and above regex, it works. So can you explain what you are aiming for?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in you .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

hope it help's...

Comment: @daulat Ok, you need to set the same thing to other folder:
`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php`

Here's a good tutorial:
[https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/]